# Scala how to get last calculated value of stream?

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation, memoization, scala-streams

According to scala docs stream implements lazy lists where elements are only evaluated when they are needed. Example;

```
val fibs: Stream[BigInt] = BigInt(0) #:: BigInt(1) #:: fibs.zip(fibs.tail).map(n => { 
    n._1 + n._2
})
```

After that in scala repl;

```
fibs(4)
fibs
```

It will print out;

res1: Stream[BigInt] = Stream(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, ?)

Since calling **.length** or **.last** causes infinite loop,how can I get value "3" (last calculated value) in most efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. This is not part of the API of `Stream`. And with reason, because that would allow you to observe a value that changes over time from a `Stream`, and that violate the (lazy) immutable nature of `Stream`.